# Calculating MAX_ITER for detectron2: Faster R-CNN Training

Tags: object-detection, detectron

Given a dataset of 5000 images split into training (4000), validation (500), and test (500) sets, I aim to train a Faster R-CNN model using detectron2 over 150 epochs with a batch size of 16. How can I calculate the appropriate value for MAX_ITER, representing the maximum number of iterations, based on these parameters?

Want to get the max_iteration number